# How to compare two values in different sheets and return difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

`Sheet1` and `Sheet2` contain cells (`in column A`), with their neighbor cells (`in Column C`). `Column E` uses a countif formula to count the number of neighbors for each cell;  `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)`.

I have a formula in `Column F` of `Sheet1` that sums up the values in `Column E` of both sheets (`Sheet1` and `Sheet2`) and returns the difference if the total value is greater than `2`, otherwise it returns `0`. The code is below :

`=MAX(0,E1+IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Sheet2!E2E,Sheet2!A:A,C1,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!C:C!),0)-2)`

However the formula does not work; it returns a error. Can someone please take a look at the formula for me.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: You have an error on the arguments of the function `averaifs`: range, range, criteria, range, range instead of range, criteria,range, criteria, range.

Comment: @Pspl I cant seem to get the values in the correct order. Any combination I tried returns the value 0

Comment: I didn't evaluate the formula. Just saw the error in the arguments of the function and commented your post...

Comment: Which total value are you referring to?

Comment: @Pspl The total of the values in column E of both sheets

Comment: It looks like you have an extra 'E' in the formula after `Sheet2!E2`, or maybe the `2` should be a `:`.

Comment: I don't exactly follow follow you code but: `=MAX(0,E1+IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Sheet2!E2,Sheet2!A:A,C1,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!C:C),0)-2)`.  You apear to have an extra 2 and an extra !.  Removing those should cause it to not return an error